# C++ function call question

Tags: c++, function

i have a question about the function call in the following example:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin  >> a >> b >> endl;
    cout << *f(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

So is *f(a,b) a valid function call?

Edit:: sorry for the errors, i fixed them now i'm a little tired

Comment: Maybe you'd like to expand on what `f` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code at least *could* be reasonable. For it to work, `f` must be defined as a function that returns either of two sorts of things: either it returns a pointer, in which case the `*` dereferences the pointer, so whatever it was pointing *at* gets sent to standard output. Otherwise, `f` must return some user-defined type that defines `operator *` to return something that's compatible with `cout`.

Comment: Ok so if the function were to return the sum of the numbers the call isn't valid?

Comment: @Vlad: the answer depends on the *type* used to hold the sum. If it's `int`, `long`, `double` (etc.), then no, not valid. If it's some UDT that defines a (unary) `operator*`, then yes (though the latter seems unlikely).

Answer (score 6):

Whatever `f` is, `*f(a, b)` attempts to apply the indirection operator to the result of `f(a, b)`.

If `f` is a function pointer and you're trying to call it, while you could do this:

```
(*f)(a, b)
```

Just doing `f(a, b)` is simpler.

Comment: @Vlad: Maybe you should add that to the question so we don't have to try and read your mind, eh? In that case, it applies indirection to whatever `f(a, b)` returns. (And if it cannot do that, your program is ill-formed. That is, `f` needs to either return a pointer or a class-type with the unary `operator*` overloaded.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to tell without seeing the definition of f.  C++ requires a lot of context to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is very tough to tell if it is valid or not without knowing what `'f'` is. But if it returns something that can be `dereferenced` it looks fine as long as that `'dereferenced'` value can be printed `(an overloaded operator <<)` should exist for the type.